# Database Trigger on Column Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-design, triggers

What I want to do in the db is have MYFUNC()

I then want to send a query down to the db in the form of

```
select * from foo where col = 'my name'
```

and have the database handle it like:

```
select * from foo where MYFUNC(col) = MYFUNC('my name')
```

So I want my db functions to be hidden to the developer. I want them to match based on a matching algorithm but when the noobs look at it, they will say, 'Oh, Ill just match the name to the name and be done with it!'

Is there a way to hide this function so the developer does not need to remember to use the function each time?

This is in PostgresSQL 9.2 by the way.

Comment: Be careful about performance implications of [putting a column in a black box](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions/case-insensitive-search). Assuming `col` is indexed, the first query is index seek, but the second is full table scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encapsulate it in a plain SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_foo(text)
  RETURNS SETOF foo AS
$func$
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE myfunc(col) = myfunc($1)
$func$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then the call would be:

```
SELECT * FROM f_get_foo('my name');
```

Triggers are not directly applicable for this.
You *could* use [**rules**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules.html) on a table or view to bend things. But I am not going to assist with such a dubious approach.

Comment: I think upon further discussion with my boss, we will abandon this idea. Thanks for the answer though. If I were to do it a function would be the way to go.